# Send mongoose data to frontend JavaScript with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, fetch

I have a question.

My Express app routes "http://localhost:8000/" to my index.html, this is a static file, I am not using a template engine. This index.html has a normal JavaScript-file (called frontend.js) attached to it, to interact with the DOM. In the frontend.js there is a GET request using the Fetch api to the URL "/get-list", like this:

```
fetch("/get-list", {
        method: "GET",         
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"}
        }).then(response => {response.json();
        }).then(data => {console.log("Data:", data);});
```

In my Express app I have a GET route setup for this fetch, like this:

```
const titles = [];
app.get("/get-list", (req, res) => {
    Book.find()
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
    })
    .catch ((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

The Book instance represents a mongoose Model. As you can see the "/get-list" route searches through my database and stores the result in the result variable. The log I get in the console is the expected result. But when I try to retrieve this data in my frontend.js it returns "undefined" in the console.log("Data:", data);

So my actual question is: how do I send data from my database to the frontend using the fetch GET request? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to return the `Promise` returned by `response.json()` from the callback function of first `then()`. Either add an explicit return statement or remove the curly brackets around `response.json()` ---> `.then(response => response.json())`

Comment: @Yousaf Yes this worked! Thank you! But could you maybe explain why I had to remove the curly brackets? Does this have to do with how arrow functions work?

Comment: Yes, if curly brackets are present then you have to add an explicit return statement, otherwise `undefined` is returned from the function. Removing the curly brackets implicitly returns the `Promise` returned by `response.json()`